# Prometheus: grouping metrics by metric names

Tags: prometheus

Is there a way to group all metrics of an app by metric names? A portion from a query listing all metrics for an app (i.e. `{app="bar"}`) :

```
ch_qos_logback_core_Appender_all_total{affiliation="foo",app="bar", instance="baz-3-dasp",job="kubernetes-service-endpoints",kubernetes_name="bar",kubernetes_namespace="foobarz",kubernetes_node="mypaas-dev-node3.fud.com",updatedBy="janedoe"}   44
ch_qos_logback_core_Appender_debug_total{affiliation="foo",app="bar", instance="baz-3-dasp",job="kubernetes-service-endpoints",kubernetes_name="bar",kubernetes_namespace="foobarz",kubernetes_node="mypaas-dev-node23.fud.com",updatedBy="deppba"} 32
```

I have also tried to use wildcard in the metric name, prometheus is complaining about that. Looking at the metrics, I can see that some of them have dynamic names, most probably delivered by dropwizard metrics. What I ultimately want is a list of all available metrics.

Comment: What do you mean by grouping? What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: what i mean is that I am after finding all available metrics.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The following query lists all available metrics:

```
sum by(__name__)({app="bar"})
```

Where `bar` is the application name, as you can see in the log entries posted in the question.

Comment: count by, instead of sum to see how many samples you have collected with that name

Answer (score 23):

`{__name__=~".+"}` will return all non-stale time series, however this is an expensive query and should be generally avoided.

Comment: Yes, but it is only to figure out which metrics are there. Tried the query. Error executing query: Gateway Time-out.

Comment: Error executing query: invalid parameter 'query': 1:1: parse error: metric name must not be set twice: "metric_name" or ".+"

Answer (score 20):

Using directly

```
{__name__=~".+"}
```

will return `success` but nothing else (too big).

or

```
{__name__=~".*"}
```

while will give us `error` instead as expected:

```
parse error at char 17: vector selector must contain at least one non-empty matcher
```

So my trick here is combining the solutions of brian-brazil and naimdjon using things like

```
sum({__name__=~"c.*|e.*|n.*|p.*|r.*|k.*|z.*|r.*"}) by (__name__)
```

1. since I know the possible `prefixes`, so I add them to query to make sure at lest it will return something; and further,
2. to avoid useless fields returned (stressing out the Prometheus), I will only require `__name__` in this way `by(__name__)`, all the names of the metrics I need returned as expected.

Actually there is an `API` to get all the available metric names as:

```
/api/v1/label/__name__/values
```

Comment: I would put the last part in **BOLD** at the top of your answer.

Comment: I second that.  The last example is perfect

Comment: `{__name__=~".*"}`

just use ".+"